# Can't get data from request

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new to json and can't get data from request correct.
I haven't got any problems with `getDrivers()`, but when I try to get data from     `getDriverRaces($scope.id)` I get nothing.
I've tried to do it manualy: `http://ergast.com/api/f1/2015/drivers/hamilton/results.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`
and result was - 
[image]

```
      angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).

  controller('driversController', function ($scope, ergastAPIservice) {
      $scope.nameFilter = null;
      $scope.driversList = [];
      $scope.searchFilter = function (driver) {
          var re = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
          return !$scope.nameFilter || re.test(driver.Driver.givenName) || re.test(driver.Driver.familyName);
      };

      ergastAPIservice.getDrivers().success(function (response) {
          $scope.driversList = response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
      });
  }).

  controller('driverController', function ($scope, $routeParams, ergastAPIservice) {
      $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
      $scope.races = [];
      $scope.driver = null;

      ergastAPIservice.getDriverRaces($scope.id).success(function (response) {
          $scope.races = response.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
      });
  });
```

---

```
 <div class="main-content">
        <table class="result-table">
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="5">Formula 1 2015 Results</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Round</td>
                    <td>Grand Prix</td>
                    <td>Team</td>
                    <td>Grid</td>
                    <td>Race</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="race in races">
                    <td>{{race.round}}</td>
                    <td>{{race.raceName}}</td>
                    <td>{{race.Results[0].Constructor.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{race.Results[0].grid}}</td>
                    <td>{{race.Results[0].position}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

---

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp.services', [])
  .factory('ergastAPIservice', function ($http) {

      var ergastAPI = {};

      ergastAPI.getDrivers = function () {
          return $http({
              method: 'JSONP',
              url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2015/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
          });
      }

      ergastAPI.getDriverRaces = function (id) {
          return $http({
              method: 'JSONP',
              url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2015/drivers/' + id + '/results.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
          });
      }

      return ergastAPI;
  });
```

Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that because of carelessness I entered same controller twice, because of common name.

```
.
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
       when("/drivers", { templateUrl: "partials/drivers.cshtml", controller: "driversController" }).
       when("/drivers/:id", { templateUrl: "partials/driver.cshtml", controller: "driverController" }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: "/drivers" });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you are trying to get at the data in the success functions.

This

```
ergastAPIservice.getDriverRaces($scope.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.races = response.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
});
```

should be this (data returned from a $http call is in response.data)

```
ergastAPIservice.getDriverRaces($scope.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.races = response.data.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
});
```

The response object has the following properties ([see documentation here near top](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http))

- data - your response should be in here
- status
- headers
- config
- statusText

You are trying to access property `response.MRData` which will never exist but `response.data.MRData` should